# Avoiding Login Screen Every time the Application Restarts

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am using `Firebase` Authentication method for login in to my app.But the problem is app always asks for sign in every time the app restarts.which is very bad experience for the user.

How to configure that fact that my app dose not need to sign in  everytime the app restarts . Only the first time it has to be done..[the similar is handled by firebase auth ui -but i am not using Firebase auth ui here , instead using simple firebase sign in authentication ]

How to obtain that desired functionality?

Comment: Store user data in shared preference once login / authentication successful from firebase auth and check every restart of application is value is exists or not if exists than redirect to your main screen otherwise redirect to login screen

Comment: yes i have thought of that but it will store only the login credentials....but it will not handle the complete process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
     //user is logged
 } else {
    //prompt logg to the user
}
```